# On Esc, toggle bootstrap dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Generally, on `Esc` any dialog disappears. But we want the functionality to launch the bootstrap dialog on `Esc` and close it on next `Esc` .
So this is my code:

```
1.$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
2.  if(e.which == 27 && id == "#esc"){
3.      if(!$(dialogid).is(":visible")){
4.          $(dialogid).modal({'show':true, 'keyboard':false});         
5.        }else{
6.          $(dialogid).modal('hide');
7.      }
8.  }
9.});
```

It works fine until I press the `Esc` key slowly. But sometimes if user keeps pressing `Esc` key faster multiple times, then the dialog disappears permanently. The control reaches to line no 4. i.e.

```
$(dialogid).modal({'show':true, 'keyboard':false});
```

but this line doesn't launch the popup.

- What could be the reason?
- How can I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove 
`{'show':true, 'keyboard':false}`

and only keep

```
$(dialogid).modal('show')
```

**Ex:**

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
   if(e.which == 27){
      if(!$('#myModal').is(":visible")){
          $('#myModal').modal('show');         
        }else{
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      }
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g535g20n/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Use `setTimeout` to run in different threads

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/g535g20n/1/)**

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e){
   if(e.which == 27){
      if(!$('#myModal').is(":visible")){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');         
          },100);
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            },100);
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: No, not working. same situation. checked in your demo :(

Comment: what is not working?? :o  how you are checking in my DEMO?

Comment: Try pressing `Esc` key multiple times without stopping. ( 3-4 times in a second) Esc dialog will disappear permanently.

Comment: Great, Seems working. Can you please explain me why you did that so?  I mean what was the reason it was not working.

Comment: Well as of my knowledge both the actions `hiding` and `keypress` where running in same thread which actually creates problem on series of actions being continuously executed. So when using `setTimeout` it will create a separate thread and run the hide/show and `keypress` in different threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86867/discussion-between-laxmikant-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: If we press esc little faster then it is still reproducible!